# How to consume a WCF Rest service with TransportClientCredentialsOnly security mode?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

I spent a day to figure out how to consume a wcf rest service with TransactionCredentialOnly security mode, with client type and proxy type are `Windows`

But I missed something I don't know.

The service host and the calling code are in same machine (of course, I'm debugging)
This is the response, `Unauthorized`. I expected it is success state, but it is not.

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcU2ltdWxhdG9yXEJyb2tlcmFnZUZpcm1cUHJvZmlsZVNlcnZpY2Uuc3ZjXGdyb3Vwcw==?=
  Cache-Control: private
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
  WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Wed, 08 Oct 2014 09:41:53 GMT
  Content-Length: 6088
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}
```

I have a WCF Rest service with method:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class IProfileService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "groups")]
    IList<Group> ListGroups();
}
```

Web.config

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="MyNamespace.ProfileService">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RestFulBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding" name="ProfileServiceRestEndpoint" bindingName="ProfileServiceRestBinding" contract="MyNamespace.IProfileService" />
  </service>


<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestFulBehavior">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="None" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

And the console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:3522/ProfileService.svc/groups").Result;

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

WCF Project's IIS Config

```
Always Start When Debugging: True
Anonymous Authentication: Enabled
Managed Pipeline Mode: Intergrated
SSL Enabled: True
SSL URL: localhost:44300
URL: localhost:3522
Windows Authentication: Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the windows authentication mode has not been enabled for this service. Can you try enabling the windows Authetication in IIS.

If the service is running on IIS express, then change the applicationhost.config(located at ..\Documents\IIS Express\config) to enable the windows authentication.